# In Automic 12 bash, special characters in mailx body result in body being attached as a binary file

Tags: linux, bash, email, mailx, automic

I am trying to send an email using mailx through Automic Workload Automation 12.0's bash jobs. The message needs to have a special character, in this case the percent sign "°".

The message should have the body `This is the ° sign.`, for this example.

I am using this code to send the message. `printf '\xB0'` prints the ° sign.

```
(
  printf 'This is the '
  printf '\xB0'
  printf ' sign.'
) | mailx [etc]
```

If I copy and paste this directly into a bash terminal, the email sends fine with the special character printed in the message body.

However, when I use the same code in Automic bash jobs, the email body is blank. There is a file attached, named `ATT00001.bin`. If I open `ATT00001.bin` using notepad.exe, the file contains the text that should have been in the body, `This is the ° sign.` With the characters printed exactly as they should be in the body.

The following when used in Automic results in a message being sent with the correct body. No files are attached. So it seems clear that the special character is causing this issue with Automic.

```
(
  printf 'This is the '
  printf 'placeholder'
  printf ' sign.'
) | mailx [etc]
```

Does anyone know why this happens, or how to resolve it?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! Try using html' ascii encoding:  *`<html><body>This is the &deg; sign.</body></html>`*

Comment: I switched to `sendmail` and used the `&deg;` notation as you suggested. Somehow this doesn't seem very satisfying, but it worked.

Comment: @F.Hauri If you would like to submit an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailx is a evolved MUA. For just sending a mail, if you use `sendmail`, you could build your own mail header:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail destuser@desthost <<eomail
To: destuser@desthost
Subject: Any interesting thing
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is the ° sign
eomail
```

Or you could use html encoding:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail destuser@desthost <<eomail
To: destuser@desthost
Subject: Any interesting thing
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html><body>This is the &deg; sign</body></html>
eomail
```

Care, use only ASCII characters there!